# Using predict() with RcppArmadillo/RcppEigen when a factor level has only one level

Tags: r, rcpp, predict

I have a question regarding the use of the `predict()` function with the `RcppArmadillo` and `RcppEigen` packages, when a factor variable has only one level. I built a MWE below using the `iris` dataset.

I want to first estimate a linear regression model using `RcppArmadillo`, and then use it to predict values. The data I use for estimation contains factor variables (with more than one level and no `NA`). The prediction I want to make is slightly unusual in one respect: I want to predict values using the same factor level for all observations (this level being in levels used in the estimation). In the example below, it means that I want to predict `Sepal.Length` as if all observations were from the "versicolor" Species.

This works well when I estimate the model using the `lm()` function, but does not work with the `RcppArmadillo::fastLm()` or `RcppEigen::fastLm()` functions. I get the following error: `` Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels ``. The same error happens again if one of the factor levels is missing. I understand well why at least two levels are necessary for estimation, but I don't understand why having only one level is a problem for prediction once the model has been properly estimated.

The obvious solution would be to use `lm()` instead of `fastLm()`, but this is unfortunately impossible because my data is quite big. After some trial-and-error, I found this dirty work-around:

- I stack two versions of the data: the first one is the original data (with all factor levels), the second one is the modified data (with the same factor level for all observations);
- I predict values on this dataset (it works because all factor levels are present in this dataset);
- I keep only the modified subset of data.

Does anyone have a better solution than this, or at least an explanation as to why this error exists?

```
library(data.table)

# Loading iris data
iris <- as.data.table(iris)

# Estimating the model
model <-
  RcppArmadillo::fastLm(Sepal.Length ~ 
                 factor(Species)
               + Sepal.Width 
               + Petal.Length 
               + Petal.Width,
               data=iris)

summary(model)

#### 
#### Here is the error I don't understand
#### 

# This is the standard use of the predict function
iris2 <- copy(iris)
iris2[, predict := predict(model, iris2)]

# This is the way I want to use the predict function
# This does not work for some reason
iris2 <- copy(iris)
iris2[, Species := "versicolor"]
iris2[, predict2 := predict(model, iris2)]

#### 
#### This is a dirty work-around
#### 

# Creating a modified dataframe
iris3 <- copy(iris)
iris3[, `:=`(Species = "versicolor",
             data = "Modified data")]

# copying the original dataframe
iris4 <- copy(iris)
iris4[, data := "Original data"]

# Stacking the original data and the modified data
iris5 <- rbind(iris3, iris4)
iris5[, predict := predict(model, iris5)]

# Keeping only the modified data
iris_final <- iris5[data == "Modified data"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a solution, but an explanation for why it happens.

If we inspect the source code of `RcppAramdillo:::predict.fastLm()`, we find that it constructs the design matrix for the prediction points via

```
x <- model.matrix(object$formula, newdata)
```

On the other hand, if we inspect the source for `stats::predict.lm()`, we find

```
tt <- terms(object)
## Some source omitted here
Terms <- delete.response(tt)
m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels)
if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses")))  .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
X <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts.arg = object$contrasts)
```

which reveals that `lm()` stores in its result information about the factor levels and contrasts for predictors, while `fastLm()` reconstructs that information in the `predict()` call:

```
names(model)
# [1] "coefficients"  "stderr"        "df.residual"   "fitted.values"
# [5] "residuals"     "call"          "intercept"     "formula"      
names(lm_mod) ## Constructed with `lm()` call with same formula
#  [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"         
#  [5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"  
#  [9] "contrasts"     "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"        
# [13] "model"
```

Note the `"xlevels"` and `"contrasts"` elements in an `lm` object that are not present in a `fastLm` object. This goes to a larger point, though, from `help("fastLM")`:

> Linear models should be estimated using the lm function. In some cases, lm.fit may be appropriate.

Dirk can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the point of `fastLm()` is not to provide a rich OLS implementation that covers all the use cases that `stats::lm()` does; I think it's more illustrative.

If your problem is big data and that's why you don't want to use `stats::lm()`, might I suggest something like `biglm::biglm()`? (See, for example, [here](https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/lm-iii-bigdata.html)). If you are really set on using `RcppArmadillo::fastLm()`, you could do a smaller version of your workaround; instead of copying your whole data, just append one row to your prediction set for each unused factor level.

Comment: Thanks a lot `duckmayr` for this detailed explanation! I must say I had limited knowledge of RcppArmadillo, so I might have used `fastLm` in a way it wasn't designed for. I'm not planning to use `biglm`, because my data fits in memory. Thanks also for the tip on the workaround, I will follow your advice. Thanks!